# Facebook links keep opening inside the app

Tags: facebook

In my facebook app I have checked the option to open links externally, but some links still open internally. Is there a way to stop this? ALL links must open externally. Version 87.0.0.7.78, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the instant articles? If so they can only be displayed in app (however, after opening one, press the share button [top right] to open in in your browser).

Comment: No, not just the instant articles. Some links open externally like they are supposed to, and some do not.

Comment: Then I have no idea, have you tried clearing app data then uninstalling (make sure you clear data first)?